# How to get 2 or multiple custom post types in wordpress functions.php

Tags: php, posts, customization

I using the below code to get modified data for the post, but I need to get the same modified post for my other custom posts. For example, it works if i change post to test( my custom post type name)"if( 'post' === get_post_type() )", but i need for both test, post and movies etc.

```
function et_last_modified_date_blog( $the_date ) {
    if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) {
        $the_time = get_post_time( 'His' );
        $the_modified = get_post_modified_time( 'His' );

        $last_modified =  sprintf( __( 'Last updated %s', 'Divi' ), esc_html( get_post_modified_time( 'M j, Y' ) ) );
        $date = $the_modified !== $the_time ? $last_modified : get_post_time( 'M j, Y' );

        return $date;
    }
}
add_action( 'get_the_date', 'et_last_modified_date_blog' );
add_action( 'get_the_time', 'et_last_modified_date_blog' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your if statement just add more conditions like this.

```
function et_last_modified_date_blog( $the_date ) {
    if ( 'post' === get_post_type() || 'movies' === get_post_type() || 'etc' === get_post_type()) {
        $the_time = get_post_time( 'His' );
        $the_modified = get_post_modified_time( 'His' );

        $last_modified =  sprintf( __( 'Last updated %s', 'Divi' ), esc_html( get_post_modified_time( 'M j, Y' ) ) );
        $date = $the_modified !== $the_time ? $last_modified : get_post_time( 'M j, Y' );

        return $date;
    }
}
add_action( 'get_the_date', 'et_last_modified_date_blog' );
add_action( 'get_the_time', 'et_last_modified_date_blog' );
```

The "||" means OR.  So the condition would read If post type equals post or movies or etc.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `in_array`.   Also you do not return the original date if your check fails.  See code below for fix.

```
function et_last_modified_date_blog( $the_date ) {
    // all post types were are checking for
    $post_types = array('post', 'movies');

    // check to see if current post type is in the $post_types array
    if (in_array(get_post_type(), $post_types)) {
        $the_time = get_post_time( 'His' );
        $the_modified = get_post_modified_time( 'His' );

        $last_modified =  sprintf( __( 'Last updated %s', 'Divi' ), esc_html( get_post_modified_time( 'M j, Y' ) ) );
        $date = $the_modified !== $the_time ? $last_modified : get_post_time( 'M j, Y' );

        return $date;
    }

    // NOTE: you should return the original date here in case your check "fails"
    return $the_date;
}
add_action( 'get_the_date', 'et_last_modified_date_blog' );
add_action( 'get_the_time', 'et_last_modified_date_blog' );
```

Comment: Thank you, this one worked for me ...

Comment: Great, glad this worked for you!